# BUG: PHP pre-increment and post-increment variable for array keys

Tags: php, bug-tracking

```
<?php
$options = array();
$currentYear = 2012;

while($currentYear < (2012 + 3) ) {
    $options[$currentYear++] = $currentYear;
}

var_dump($options);
?>
```

**expected output:**

> ```
> array(3) {
>      [2012]=> int(2012)
>      [2013]=> int(2013)
>      [2014]=> int(2014)
> }
> ```

**Generic theory:** Executes the RHS of an assignment first and assigns the RHS value to LHS. It would execute post-increment in LHS after it executed the RHS. According to this scenario, we can explain the iteration as follows.

In 1st iteration, RHS $currentYear value is 2012 and assigns that value to array options with key 2012. Increment the variable $currentYear by 1, and proceed with the iteration. In 2nd iteration, RHS $currentYear value is 2013 and assigns that value to array options with key 2013. Increment the variable $currentYear by 1, and proceed with the iteration. **What happened to this generic programming concept down below?**

**Actual output:**

> ```
>  array(3) {
>      [2012]=> int(2013)
>      [2013]=> int(2014)
>      [2014]=> int(2015)
>  }
> ```

***If someone can come up with a better explanation that would be great, and much appreciate.***

Comment: Why are you using the self-answer feature to comment on your own bug report...? Or if you didn't intend for this to be a bug report, but an actual question, please format it so that it reads like a question. Bug tracking is not Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Above theory is wrong.**
[In PHP arrays have higher precedence than increment/decrement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Therefore PHP executes the array keys first (that's why first element of the array key appeared as 2012) and then goes to the assignment.

In this scenario, PHP keeps array key as `$currentYear` value 2012 and increment by 1. Then it comes to the RHS takes `$currentYear` value and assigns it to the array options with the key 2012. Likewise, it continues with the iteration.

Comment: I won't say it's wrong, it's not complete. The increment / decrement operation is after array but before assignment. See [Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.precedence.php). You need to keep both in mind to understand why it is calculating that result.

Comment: Thank you @hakre, that's what I was exactly looking for. It's very helpful resource

Comment: Consider to beautify it a little, I'd say you can make the variable names in this code-style, like `$currentYear`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep in mind the concepts of [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) and you will understand better these operators.

Post-increment returns $currentYear, then increments $currentYear by one, based in this, what is happening in your case is the following:

```
$currentYear = 2012;

$options[$currentYear++] = $currentYear;

/* Post-increment will return 2012 to the array, after this will increment it to 
 * 2013, so in the right side it will be 2013, then you'll get the result below. 
 * Remember that PHP analyses the code from left to right.
 */

$options[2012] == 2013;
```

To get your expected result you must use pre-increment because it will increment $currentYear by one, then returns $currentYear. For instance:

```
$currentYear = 2012;

$options[++$currentYear] = $currentYear;

/* Pre-increment will increment $currentYear first, after this will return the 
 * value to array, so $currentYear will have the same value in both sides. 
 * Like below.
 */

$options[2013] == 2013;
```

**EDIT 1**

As your first index and `$currentYear` must be equals you must use a different logic, something like this:

```
$options = array();
$currentYear = 2012;

while($currentYear < (2012 + 3) ) {
    $options[$currentYear] = $currentYear;

    $currentYear++; // "++$currentYear" and "$currentYear += 1" will work too
}
```

Comment: Please see the **expected output.** The current year (2012) should be the first option of the array, so you can't use post-increment in this case. The array should store current year following future years. @Marcio Thank you for your contribution

Comment: @rasanga, If the first array's index must be equal `$currentYear` you can't use Pre-increment neither Post-increment. I've done an update in my answer, you should do something like this, please see it.